# XDocument - Create XAttribute Xmlns with no prefix

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to create an XML document for input to a third party web service `(.asmx)`.  I am using `Linq to Xml`.

I am generating `XAttributes` with namespaces like so:

```
XNamespace xsiNs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsiNs);
```

This gives me the desired output of `xmlns:xsi.....` with the `xsi` prefix

However, there is an attribute with no prefix like this:  `xmlns="urn:.......`

How do I achieve adding the namespace without the prefix for that attribute only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An attribute like this `xmlns="urn:..."` is your element's namespace (and default namespace for all descendant elements) so if you want to add try this:

```
    XNamespace xsiNs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    XNamespace defNs = "urn:dummy";
    var element = new XElement(defNs + "root", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsiNs));
```

The result is the following:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:dummy" />
```